# Remove records from one datatable based on records from another datable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, datatable

I have the following results in  the first datatable:

Datatable with uploaded documents

```
clientcode    jobcode    joburl                          DocumentLink
1             1          http://ourlocaldomain.com       http://ourlocaldomain.com/documents/1.pdf
1             2          http://ourlocaldomain.com       http://ourlocaldomain.com/documents/2.pdf
```

Datatable with all client and jobs regardless if the document is uploaded or not. (the document link column is not present on this second datable)

```
clientcode    jobcode    joburl                          
1             1          http://ourlocaldomain.com       
1             2          http://ourlocaldomain.com       
1             3          http://ourlocaldomain.com    
1             4          http://ourlocaldomain.com
```

My 3rd datatable should return all records from Datatable2 which are not in datatable 1, BASED on a matching record with client code and jobcode.

I suppose this should be able to do with LINQ somehow but clueless where to start digging:

the code I have is:

```
var keywordQueryAllInfoLists = new KeywordQuery(site);
dataTableAllInfoLists = KQLUtilities.ExecuteKql(keywordQueryAllInfoLists, queryTextAllInfoLists, selectedProperties.ToArray(), keywordQueryAllInfoLists.SortList);

var keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(site);
dataTableAllEngagementLetters = KQLUtilities.ExecuteKql(keywordQuery, queryTextAllLetterOfEngagement, selectedProperties.ToArray(), keywordQuery.SortList);
```

**EDIT**
I have tried the following:

```
resultingDatatable = dataTableAllEngagementLetters.Select()
                    .Where(x => !dataTableAllInfoLists.Select(string.Format("ClientCode = {0} and JobCode = {1}", x["ClientCode"], x["JobCode"]))
                    .Any())
                    .CopyToDataTable();


resultingDatatable = dataTableAllEngagementLetters.Select()
                    .Where(x => !dataTableAllInfoLists.Select(string.Format("ClientCode = [{0}] and JobCode = [{1}]", x["ClientCode"], x["JobCode"]))
                    .Any())
                    .CopyToDataTable();
```

These 2 throw me the following exception: http://screencast.com/t/HWLZTOJEn8T

```
  resultingDatatable = dataTableAllEngagementLetters.Select()
                        .Where(x => !dataTableAllInfoLists.Select(string.Format("ClientCode = '{0}' and JobCode = '{1}'", x["ClientCode"], x["JobCode"]))
                        .Any())
                        .CopyToDataTable();
```

And this last one tells me there are to rows on the source!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very nice but it's the first solution that came in my mind:

```
DataTable dataTable3 = dataTable2.Select().Where(x => dataTable1.Select(string.Format("clientCode = '{0}' and jobCode = '{1}'", x["clientCode"], x["jobCode"])).Count() == 0).CopyToDataTable();
```

---

EDIT

`Count == 0` you can change to `!Any()`. So should look like this:

```
DataTable dataTable3 = dataTable2.Select().Where(x => !dataTable1.Select(string.Format("clientCode = '{0}' and jobCode = '{1}'", x["clientCode"], x["jobCode"])).Any()).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: How can I rewrite that with .Any>?

Comment: I have the following error, T001 its actually a jobcode: am I missing something in the string.format? http://screencast.com/t/HWLZTOJEn8T

Comment: I dont know how you named columns so check upper case letters first. Second have your dataTableAllInfoLists those(clientCode and jobCode) columns?

Comment: Indeed it was JobCode and ClientCode, camel case, but that didnt solve the problem, I tried using brackets on the select, but still the same problem. http://screencast.com/t/UJlCXSJJ

Comment: Still cant understand what is T001? is it column name in dataTableAllInfoLists?

Comment: Its a value of the JobCode field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61763/discussion-between-esteban-v-and-reniuz).